# Proteus doesn't show the value of float variables and does not attribute values to them

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, debugging, proteus

I have an issue with Proteus Isis.

The image below illustrates the problem. I can't see the values of a struct's fields and I think that Proteus can't see the struct too.

[image]

[Full Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFpXh.png)

Anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your debug files are COFF format, please check this link: http://support.labcenter.co.uk/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3770&p=12623&hilit=+dt_float+#p12623

Double click on the MCU in the ISIS workspace to brings up the edit component window. In the "other properties" edit box, add DT_FLOAT=MICROCHIP_BIGENDIAN

Comment: I have not found that option. Is it in Proteus?

Comment: Just in your workspace, on your PIC MCU.

Comment: You should create a **new** properties, **DT_FLOAT**

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the last paragraph of your answer. Was edited?